# Can't make ImageView a circle in a Custom Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to display a rounded image for every custom cell in a table view. I am already changing its cornerRadius, but for some reason the image  still will appear fully - even when the ImageView's borders are already set round.

Here's a piece of the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CustomTableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celda", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.imgView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgView.frame.height/2

        //...the rest of function
        //image is added to imgView eventually
}
```

[And here is the result in the sim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xKEZ.png)

I tried putting the code in override func awakeFromNib in the cell file but I had the same result.

Any advice is welcome :)

Comment: “Clip to bounds” in IB. Or `cell.imgView.clipsToBounds = true` in code.

Comment: A cell's frame (nor its content's frames) are set when `cellForRowAt` is called. The proper solution is to create round images, not apply a corner radius to the image view.

Comment: @rmaddy Nothing wrong with setting mask on the image view. But I’d do it in [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) of `CustomTableViewCell` class, capturing the original size (and gracefully handling if the image view changes size). Or, better, a designable `UIImageView` designable subclass that rounds the corners in its own `layoutSubviews`. But you’re quite right that this sort of code doesn’t really belong in the `UIViewControllerDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code by following step:

step1:

Make the height and width same of `image view`. Add the `1:1 ratio` in storyboard in `image view` for equal height and width.

step2:

```
cell.imgView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgView.frame.height/2
cell.imgView.clipsToBounds = true
```

It may helps you.Thank you.